# Aggregating and Renaming Keys in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, rename

I have a word occurrence dictionary, and a synonym dictionary.

Word occurrence dictionary example:

```
word_count = {'grizzly': 2, 'panda': 4, 'beer': 3, 'ale': 5}
```

Synonym dictionary example:

```
synonyms = {
            'bear': ['grizzly', 'bear', 'panda', 'kodiak'],
            'beer': ['beer', 'ale', 'lager']
           }
```

I would like to comibine/rename aggregate the word count dictionary as

```
new_word_count = {'bear': 6, 'beer': 8}
```

I thought I would try this:

```
new_dict = {}
for word_key, word_value in word_count.items():           # Loop through word count dict
    for syn_key, syn_value in synonyms.items():           # Loop through synonym dict
        if word_key in [x for y in syn_value for x in y]: # Check if word in synonyms
            if syn_key in new_dict:                       # If so:
                new_dict[syn_key] += word_value           #   Increment count
            else:                                         # If not:
                new_dict[syn_key] = word_value            #   Create key
```

But this isn't working, new_dict ends up empty.  Also, is there an easier way to do this?  Maybe using dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dict comprehension, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
In [11]: {w: sum(word_count.get(x, 0) for x in ws) for w, ws in synonyms.items()}
Out[11]: {'bear': 6, 'beer': 8}
```

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
from collections import Counter
ec = Counter()
for x, vs in synonyms.items():
    for v in vs:
        ec[x] += word_count.get(v, 0)
print(ec) # Counter({'bear': 6, 'beer': 8})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's change your synonym dictionary a little. Instead of mapping from a word to a list of all its synonyms, let's map from a word to its parent synonym (i.e. `ale` to `beer`). This should speed up lookups

```
synonyms = {
            'bear': ['grizzly', 'bear', 'panda', 'kodiak'],
            'beer': ['beer', 'ale', 'lager']
           }
synonyms = {syn:word for word,syns in synonyms.items() for syn in syns}
```

Now, let's make your aggregate dictionary:

```
word_count = {'grizzly': 2, 'panda': 4, 'beer': 3, 'ale': 5}
new_word_count = {}
for word,count in word_count:
    word = synonyms[word]
    if word not in new_word_count:
        new_word_count[word] = 0
    new_word_count[word] += count
```

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me find the bug in my original code.  I went with the prior answer's dictionary comprehension for the brevity.